# Kill process using constant high CPU

Tags: linux, bash, kill

Using the following bash script that does the job just fine when it comes to killing the process if it reaches 70% CPU usage, however, since the process can legit use that much CPU for a short period of time I am getting false-positives and the process is getting killed even though I don't want to. The script makes use of the time (in seconds) but it only counts it as the process uptime and not as the high CPU usage for that amount of seconds.

I am trying so the process only gets kill if it uses 70% CPU or more for a constant 30 seconds or more, should the process use >70% CPU for a few seconds only then the process shouldn't be killed.

I'm looking to implement this directly into the script and not via a 3rd party application like monit.

```
#!/bin/bash

#max cpu % load
MAX_CPU=70
#max execution time for CPU percentage > MAX_CPU (in seconds)
MAX_SEC=30
#sort by cpu
SORTBY=9

#define a processes command name to check
declare -a KILLLIST
KILLLIST=("CSS2")

#iterate for each process to check in list
for PROCESS_TOCHECK in ${KILLLIST[*]}
do

    #retrive pid with top command order by SORTBY
    PID=$(top -bcSH -n 1 | grep $PROCESS_TOCHECK | sort -k $SORTBY -r | head -n 1 | awk '{print $1}')

    CPU=$(top -p $PID -bcSH -n 1 | grep $PROCESS_TOCHECK | sort -k $SORTBY -r | head -n 1 | awk '{print $9}')
    TIME_STR=$(top -p $PID -bcSH -n 1 | grep $PROCESS_TOCHECK | sort -k $SORTBY -r | head -n 1 | awk '{print $11}')

    #format integer cpu
    CPU=${CPU%%[.,]*}
    
    # Decode the top CPU time format [dd-]hh:mm.ss.
    TIME_SEC=0
    IFS="-:" read c1 c2 c3 c4 <<< "$TIME_STR"

    #with top command time format is hh:mm.ss, so truncare seconds in c2
    c2=${c2%%.*}

    if [ -n "$c4" ]
    then
      TIME_SEC=$((10#$c4+60*(10#$c3+60*(10#$c2+24*10#$c1))))
    elif [ -n "$c3" ]
    then
      if [ "$CMD" = "ps" ]; then
        TIME_SEC=$((10#$c3+60*(10#$c2+60*10#$c1)))
      else
        TIME_SEC=$(((10#$c3*24)*60*60)+60*(10#$c2+60*10#$c1))             
      fi   
    else
      if [ "$CMD" = "ps" ]; then
        TIME_SEC=$((10#0+(10#$c2+60*10#$c1)))
      else
        TIME_SEC=$((10#0+60*(10#$c2+60*10#$c1)))
      fi
    fi

    #check if need to kill process
    if [ $CPU -gt $MAX_CPU ] && [ $TIME_SEC -gt $MAX_SEC ]; then
        kill -9 $PID
    fi

done
```

Comment: So ... in the comments below you said you can't use tools like `monit` ... could you use e,g, `python` instead of `bash`, though?

Comment: I'm trying to have this running exclusively through bash.

Comment: In that case: have fun implementing a data structure that mimics a fifo in bash ;)   Python's `deque` would have made a great fit to your needs.

Comment: I mean if there's no other choice and bash alone isn't that viable I guess phyton would do too although I'm clueless when it comes to phyton. If you don't mind, how would the phyton syntax look like in this case so it kills the process or execute a command if the set process is using 70% CPU or more continously for 30 seconds?

Comment: I'm sure it can be done in bash; it's just nothing I'd want to try and implement, I'll hazard a guess that functions to put, pop, and iterate over the content of the data structure would be quite sizeable in terms of the code-base.  As for in python: I'd make that loop use a 1 second sleep, pop the oldest element out of the data structure, add the new measurement, and then check each element for a value >= 70. `queue = deque([70,71,71,73,71,70,72,73,75,74,71])`  ...  `all(x >= 70 for x in queue)`

Comment: Have you had any joy/made any progress on this?

Comment: Unfortunately no progress with bash and no experience with python although I found some similar script requests in phython on linux which I will give a try and see how it goes. Thanks.